# Select rows from specific date with left join

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm currently working on a simple employee scheduling tool and have a problem with a SQL query. To explain my problem let use this two very abstract tables.

The first table simply consists of the employees

```
employees
======================
empId | name    | ...
----------------------
10    | Scott   |
11    | Schrute |
12    | Halpert |
13    | Howard  |
```

In the second table you find the assigned tasks to each employee by day.

```
tasks
==============================================
tasId | name    | task     | date       | ...
----------------------------------------------
10    | Scott   | Support  | 2014-02-17 |
11    | Scott   | Bugfix   | 2014-02-18 |
12    | Halpert | Bugfix   | 2014-02-17 |
13    | Halpert | Develop  | 2014-02-18 |
14    | Howard  | Support  | 2014-02-17 |
```

Now I want to know what the employees are working on on Feb 17th or if they have no tasks planned for that day. I use the following SQL query to do that.

```
SELECT e.name, t.task
FROM employees e LEFT JOIN tasks t ON e.name = t.name
WHERE date IS NULL OR date = DATE('2014-02-17')
```

The result delivers exactly what I need:

```
name    | task
--------------------
Scott   | Support
Schrute | NULL
Halpert | Bugfix
Howard  | Support
```

And now to my problem. If I want to see the tasks of Feb 18th I get this result set:

```
name    | task
--------------------
Scott   | Bugfix
Schrute | NULL
Halpert | Develop
```

The reason to this is obvious, the date of Howard's tasks are neither NULL nor do they equal 2014-02-18.. What would be the best way to get the desired result?

I use MySQL and PHP.

(Sorry for the stupid title, I couldn't think of anything better..)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move your filter to the join predicate:

```
SELECT e.name, t.task
FROM employees e 
LEFT JOIN tasks t ON e.name = t.name AND t.date = DATE('2014-02-18');
```

Your query as it is will only return people who have no tasks at all, or have tasks on the date specified. It will omit people who have tasks, but not on the date specified. Consider the results of joining your sample data with no where clause:

```
empId | name    | task     | date       | ...
----------------------------------------|
10    | Scott   | Support  | 2014-02-17 |
10    | Scott   | Bugfix   | 2014-02-18 |
11    | Schrute | NULL     |   NULL     |
12    | Halpert | Bugfix   | 2014-02-17 |
12    | Halpert | Develop  | 2014-02-18 |
13    | Howard  | Support  | 2014-02-17 |
```

As you can see there is no record for Howard where `Date` = 2014-02-18, or where `Date` is null, this is why no record is returned for Howard. When you add the filter to the join predicate your results become:

```
empId | name    | task     | date       | ...
----------------------------------------|
10    | Scott   | Bugfix   | 2014-02-18 |
11    | Schrute | NULL     |   NULL     |
12    | Halpert | Develop  | 2014-02-18 |
13    | Howard  | NULL     |   NULL     |
```

Which I think is the desired results.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
UNIX_TIMESTAMP(`date`) = 0
```

Looks like you have some data which are stored as '0000-00-00' and its not null so adding the extra OR condition as above will return those data as well.